# will an on demand ec2 instance with root device ebs restart normally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I'm new to AWS. I have a Maverick Ubuntu installed on demand instance with root device EBS. I have a Mysql database running. Now ubuntu displays I should restart for new updates to be installed.

1. If I restart the system will it restart using root device EBS? Will there be any configuration or data losses?
2. Which way should I backup the system?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

No there will be no loss of anything due to the fact that you're using EBS.  To back up the file system you should shutdown mysql, flush the filesystem, or if you are using a filesystem that supports it, quiesce it using xfs_freeze.

This question is not really suitable for SO so I would expect it to be migrated over to Server Fault which is a good place to search for similar questions.